# Is this CSS usage valid for targeting nested divs?

Tags: css, nested, nested-class

basically just want to know if the attached image shows a valid CSS usage? I'm using a lot of nested divs lately and this is how I'm targeting them in my CSS. It works really well but I'm just curious if it's a good way of doing it? Or is there an easier / more efficient way?

Thanks!

[image: Illustration][link to the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b75DI.jpg)

Comment: You can also consider `#container div`, or `#container .content > div`, or `#container > .inner div`. I guess the fastest one will depend on the browser you use.

Comment: its valid but more efficient would be to have an id or class on the div (depending on if the style will be used more than once) and target it directly

Comment: Seems easy and efficient to me

Comment: +1 for the nice illustration :-)

Comment: It works but I hate that syntax; I find it hard to follow. I'd go with ChrisM's suggestion.

Comment: Thanks @frenchie. My problem with using #IDs is that sometimes I can unknowingly use an #ID twice within the same page, which causes problems when I target them with jQuery. Take a simple close button for example:— I sometimes have several close buttons on one page, and if I give them all an #ID of `#close-btn` I run into problems when I use `$("#close-btn")...` in my jQuery markup. Any suggestions to overcome this? Thanks.

Comment: @BenClarke: Use classes or IDs that are more specific. With classes, you'd have $('#SomePanel').find('.CloseBtn')... and with specific IDs you'd have $('#SomePanelCloseBtn')... Personally I like to combine both so that .CloseBtn is what I use to define the CSS of a close button in general and then I use the specific ID to wire up the event handling in jQuery; the HTML would be <input type="button" class="CloseBtn" id="SomePanelCloseBtn" /> and then the CSS becomes really simple: .CloseBtn{...}. More readable and easier to to code than having #content > .inner > .content > div { } for instance.

Comment: Great advice. Combining #IDs and .classes is something I'm definitely going to start doing more often. Especially with how easy jQuery makes it to `.find()` a specific class within an #ID. Thanks @frenchie

Comment: @BenClarke: yes, indeed, you should use .find() instead of $('#SomeID .SomeClass') because the latter will use the Sizzle engine whereas .find() won't and will be more efficient. Happy coding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all: yor way is totally ok and the efficiency depends on the whole page. Maybe it can get more efficient with those ideas:

**If your div-classes or ids are unique**

You can also write just the class - you dont have to write the whole path then. Instead of

```
#content > .inner > .content > div { }
```

it is possible to write for example

```
.content > div { }
```

**Helpful when you are using nested divs**

When using nested divs you very often have to type a lot of code multiple times:

```
#content > .inner > .content { }
#content > .inner > .content > div {}
#content > .inner > .footer {}
#content > .inner > .footer > div {}
```

There are very helpful scripts called **[LESS](http://lesscss.org/)** and **[SASS](http://sass-lang.com/)** (both of them work pretty much the same). They allow you to write everything just one time like

```
#content {
   .inner {
      .content {
         // some stuff
         div {
            // some stuff
         }
      }
      .footer {
         //some stuff
         div {
            // some stuff
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Wow! I had no idea about the LESS and SASS css extensions. They definitely seem like the future of css — especially the use of $variables, mixin, and extend which are such potentially powerful features. Thanks for the info.

Comment: Just one additional question: Would `#container > div` not also effect `#container > .inner` and `#container > .content` as they are also div elements within `#container`?

Comment: Not sure if I got the question. `.content > div` effects all divs within the div with the class "content". If you have more than one div within `.content` it will effect them too. But it won't effect classes outside the `.content`

Answer (score 1):

The direct child selector (ie. > ) is fine, but personally I don't like it because it makes it difficult to move and re-use styles. For example if I want to use .content somewhere other than #container I'm going to have to change a whole heap of CSS. Ideally you should be able to re-use blocks of markup without having to change CSS.

The direct child selector is best used to limit the depth to which a style is applied. For example it would be appropriate to use .content > p if you want the style to apply only to direct children so you can have another style for deeper children. If that's not the case then you might as well just use well named class and ID selectors.

Comment: this is an opinion not an answer. put it in a comment

Comment: Child selector doesn't make CSS less reusable, except if there is an id selector involved (because there won't be other elements with that id). But it would be the same with descendant selector.

Comment: @Chris M His answer question was "Is this okay?" to which I answered "The direct child selector (ie. > ) is fine", and he asked "Is there a more efficient way" to which I also answered and explained why it was more efficient (easier to reuse).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification guys. So basically there's probably a slightly more efficient way, but I'm not doing anything drastically wrong with my attached example. That's good to know. I think the problem with using div#IDs is that you can run into problems if you accidentally give 2 divs the same #ID — especially a problem when it comes to jQuery targeting. Or am I missing something? Thanks again though! @Oriol